# Will ElasticSearch rest client find out the cluster nodes automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

> I am using Rest Client of Elastic Search and Elastic Search will have
>   Nodes in a cluster.
>
> If I connect to one node then will it automatically find other nodes
>   of cluster while processing the request and do load balancing ?

**Or I need to take care of that while creating the Rest Client?**

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you? Please vote if yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "sniffer" is active, before the request (in background) the client will update your internal list of node data. It works for [default client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) and [Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/sniffer.html).
The master node (defined in the cluster configuration) will do the [load balancing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html).